# How to get the other image using jQuery

Tags: jquery

My DOM looks like this:

```
<div class="stuff">
  <a href="#"><img src=""></a> <b>hello</b>
  <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
</div>
```

Sometimes I have a reference on the first image, and sometimes on the second image.

1. When I have the first image using $() how do I select the second image?
2. When I have the second image using $() how to I select the 1st image?

Comment: Can you clarify? $(image1) from your example would not select anything.

Comment: I just meant that I have a reference to the image (when its clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.parent().nextAll("a").children("img")`
2. `.parent().prevAll("a").children("img")`

This is a fairly inelegant way to accomplish it, but it's quite explicit as to what you're looking for - almost like XPath. Once you start dealing with more than two links, you may find a technique such as those described by Ben Alpert or cletus to be more flexible (less dependent on a strict hierarchy).

Comment: Yeah. But, he's only dealing with 5 elements; ideal doesn't buy you much. I liked your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Given `myImage` as a reference to one of the images, `$(".stuff img").not(myImage)` should give you the other (or others, if you have more than two images).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the other in both cases with:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children("img").remove(this);
```

or just:

```
$("div.stuff img").remove(this);
```

Comment: I removed my answer because this is the same thing and I misread the example as being with an id :)... Personally I prefer .not(selector_or_element) to .remove because remove feels like it's a DOM manipulator.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [jQuery eq selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq).

```
var first = $('.stuff img:eq(0)');
var second = $('.stuff img:eq(1)');
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use something along the lines of

```
$('DIV.stuff:first-child')
$('DIV.stuff:nth-child(3)'
```

This will return the anchor tags which can be used to access the images. The second is nth-child(3) because nth-child(2) will return the bold tag. The ideal way though would be to apply a class or id to each image or anchor.